# Get notified on EAnnotation references list change

Tags: eclipse, emf, ecore

I'm creating a custom Ecore editor based on the [Sample Ecore editor (org.eclipse.emf.ecore* plugins)](http://git.eclipse.org/c/emf/org.eclipse.emf.git/tree/plugins) and found out that changes in lists do not manifest in model change notifications. For example, changes to the `EAnnotation.references` list will not result in model change notifications, whereas the `EAnnotation.setSource()` method creates a notification. I guess, this is one of the reasons why the default `getText()` method in the `EAnnotationItemProvider` uses only the `source` field.

I'm using the value of the `references` field to generate the UI presentation of the `EAnnotation`, so seeing the changes to this field would be necessary for correct operation.

Is there some standard way to observe these changes and fire a `refresh()` on the model views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the notification was created but the `notifyChanged()` method initially ignored it. This is what worked for me:

```
@Override
public void notifyChanged(Notification notification) {
    updateChildren(notification);

    switch (notification.getFeatureID(EAnnotation.class)) {
        case EcorePackage.EANNOTATION__SOURCE:
        case EcorePackage.EANNOTATION__REFERENCES: /*ADDED*/
            fireNotifyChanged(new ViewerNotification(notification, notification.getNotifier(), false, true));
            return;
        case EcorePackage.EANNOTATION__CONTENTS:
            fireNotifyChanged(new ViewerNotification(notification, notification.getNotifier(), true, false));
            return;
        case EcorePackage.EANNOTATION__DETAILS: /*MODIFIED TO UPDATE VIEW*/
            fireNotifyChanged(new ViewerNotification(notification, notification.getNotifier(), true, true));
            return;
    }
    super.notifyChanged(notification);
}
```